# How to make MELPA run under Windows 7?

Tags: package-repositories

I am running GNU Emacs 26.3 under Windows 7. I want to install the [Solarized theme](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs) by typing `M-x package-install solarized-theme`.

When I do this, I see the message `No match` (see below).

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

I tried to configure MELPA in my [.emacs](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/1e43ee06b53e263626db897571357b7e) file. However, I am still getting the error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: IIRC `install-package` sometimes doesn't fetch the list of packages, so make sure you run `M-x package-list-packages` first.  Otherwise, please describe in more details the steps you make (e.g. how you configured your .emacs, which you should describe right here rather than via  link to your .emacs which may contain untoil unrelated other things and may disappear or change before the next SO user looks at this question to solve his own problem).

Comment: @Stefan `M-x package-list-packages` helped, thanks. If you submit your comment as an answer, I will accept it.